# sudo npm install -g react-native ERR!Cannot find module './spawn'

Tags: node.js

npm error when I try to build the React Native environment with Mac.

---

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'react-native' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.6.0
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module './spawn'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:6:13)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
5 verbose cwd /Users/BigGIfts
6 error Darwin 15.6.0
7 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native"
8 error node v4.6.0
9 error npm  v2.15.9
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module './spawn'
12 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
12 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to build the `react-native`:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

If you get an error like:

```
Cannot find module 'npmlog'
```

Try installing npm directly: `curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

**Note**: when the error `cannot find ...` is anywhere in the error log and you did install it, it's probably either in the wrong directory or you haven't installed it yet.

Hope this helps you out ;)